# python re for opcode parsing

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

I just wrote some code to try and parse opcodes out of an objdump output of the following format :-

```
 8048060:   89 e7                   mov    edi,esp
 8048062:   89 fe                   mov    esi,edi
 8048064:   6a 6b                   push   0x6b
 8048066:   58                      pop    eax
 8048067:   aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[edi],al
 8048068:   6a 65                   push   0x65
 804806a:   58                      pop    eax
 804806b:   aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[edi],al
 804806c:   6a 79                   push   0x79
 804806e:   58                      pop    eax
 804806f:   aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[edi],al
 8048070:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 8048072:   aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[edi],al
 8048073:   40                      inc    eax
 8048074:   cd 80                   int    0x80
```

I wish to extract the opcodes as `89 e7 89 f3 .... cd 80`.
I tried using the following regex statement :-

```
opcode = ""
for line in f.readlines():
  match = re.search(r' ([\da-f]+):\s+([0-9a-f ]+)', line)
  opcode += match.group(2).strip() + " "
```

Though the above snippet kinda works for all my samples im sure that it would fail in the case where I had an instruction that ended with [a-f][space].

Could someone suggest a better regular expression for the same?

Comment: Note that what you're asking for are all the hexadecimal byte values, not just the opcodes.  The opcodes are just the first column: 89, 89, 6a, etc.  You want the arguments, too.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
r' ([\da-f]+):\s+((?:[0-9a-f]{2} )+)'
```

This should stop more reliably after the opcodes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need regular expressions. You can just `split()` the string as in the following (note: this approach works if the spaces are always exactly as shown in your sample data, which seems likely since it's generated):

```
opcodes = []
for line in f.readlines():
    opcode = []
    for x in line.split(' ')[4:]:
        if x:
            opcode.append(x)
        else:
            opcodes.append(opcode)
            break
print opcodes
```

**Output**: [['89', 'e7'], ['89', 'fe'], ['6a', '6b'], ['58'], ['aa'], ['6a', '65'], ['58'], ['aa'], ['6a', '79'], ['58'], ['aa'], ['31', 'c0'], ['aa'], ['40'], ['cd', '80']]

```
#if you need strings:
print [' '.join(sublist) for sublist in opcodes]
```

**Output**: ['89 e7', '89 fe', '6a 6b', '58', 'aa', '6a 65', '58', 'aa', '6a 79', '58', 'aa', '31 c0', 'aa', '40', 'cd 80']

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

with open("objdump") as inf:
    opstrs = (line[9:35] for line in inf)
    ops    = (opstr.split() for opstr in opstrs)
    opcode = " ".join(chain(*ops))
```

results in opcode:

```
'89 e7 89 fe 6a 6b 58 aa 6a 65 58 aa 6a 79 58 aa 31 c0 aa 40 cd 80'
```